# Filling data across a data frame when there are NAs that should be left NAs

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, na

I've been playing around with this for a while and can brute-force a solution, but am looking for a more scalable approach.

The basic question is this: How do I only replace certain values that are NA, but avoid changing NAs that should be left NAs because the data series hasn't started yet?   Here is an example:

**Reproducible example**

```
    library(tidyverse)

    # Create dummy data
    dates  <- seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-10"), by = 1)
    item_1 <- c(rep(NA,1), 1:7, NA, 8) 
    item_2 <- c(rep(NA,4), 1:3, rep(NA,2), 9) 
    item_3 <- c(rep(NA,3), 8:11, rep(NA,2), 2) 
    item_4 <- c(rep(NA,2), 1:6, rep(NA,2))

    df <- data.frame(dates, item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4)

    >df
        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA
2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA
3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1
4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5
8  2019-01-08      7     NA     NA      6
9  2019-01-09     NA     NA     NA     NA
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2     NA


# Replace NAs with zero  --------------------
df_2 <- df %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)

    > df_2
        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
1  2019-01-01      0      0      0      0
2  2019-01-02      1      0      0      0
3  2019-01-03      2      0      0      1
4  2019-01-04      3      0      8      2
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5
8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6
9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0


# Go back and replace the NAs that existed before the data of each row started

# Where the data first started (unique rows of first non-NA value)
list_of_1st_non_NAs <- unique(unlist( lapply( seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) which( !is.na(df[,x]) )[1] ) ))

# Return data frame to show where values first start
df_3 <- df[list_of_1st_non_NAs, ] %>%
  arrange(dates)
```

And here is where I am stuck.  I can see where the data starts and can therefore replace prior data with NA again for each respective column in a brute force way, but I am looking to find a way to do this more systematically.  Some usage of lapply maybe?

Thanks!

**Desired output**

```
        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA
2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA
3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1
4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5
8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6
9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, ~replace(., is.na(.) & cumsum(!is.na(.)) > 0, 0))

        dates item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
1  2019-01-01     NA     NA     NA     NA
2  2019-01-02      1     NA     NA     NA
3  2019-01-03      2     NA     NA      1
4  2019-01-04      3     NA      8      2
5  2019-01-05      4      1      9      3
6  2019-01-06      5      2     10      4
7  2019-01-07      6      3     11      5
8  2019-01-08      7      0      0      6
9  2019-01-09      0      0      0      0
10 2019-01-10      8      9      2      0
```

A slightly shorter version of replace condition, thanks to @Frank: `is.na(.) & cummax(!is.na(.))`

Comment: Shree, thanks for the quick response!  Can you explain how this works please?  It looks like you eliminate the 1st column (dates) with the -1, then you set a condition that to replace with zero, the value must be NA and the cumulative sum of not NA is >0?  This last condition gets tripped once there is a numeric value?  The data set could contain negative numbers so I wanted to make sure I understood the logic here.  Thanks!

Comment: Another way, I think: `is.na(.) & cummax(!is.na(.))`

Comment: @DaveM Check the output of `is.na(df$item_2)` and `cumsum(!is.na(df$item_2)) > 0` separately and then imagine `&` along both resulting vectors. `> 0` helps ignore the first set of `NA`s. Negative numbers will not be a problem.

Comment: Got it, I see now.  The cumsum is summing on !is.na returning a True or False, which is being read as a 1 or 0.  Many thanks!